# Вывод страницы пользователея WP через кастомный ID

Tags: wordpress, slug

Я сделал кастомное поле для профиля, в которое закидывается некие символы, например, уникальный ID.

При помощи `$wp_rewrite->author_base` изменил часть ссылки на профиль автора поста. И он имеет нужный мне вид:

https://site.com/test/user

**Вопрос:**

Как составить условие, чтоб из добавленного поля, назовём его `personal_id` ссылка на пользователя формировалась исходя из указанных данных?

Вот такого вида:

- https://site.com/test/user - без заполненного поля
- https://site.com/test/1234 - поле заполнено "1234"

Или была доступна по обоим ссылкам. Знаю, что есть бесплатные плагины с нужным функционалом, но, хотелось бы разобраться в вопросе. Спасибо!